# problem with page position after click to another navigation page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, gatsby

I am trying to create blog website using GatsbyJS, but somehow when I try to click change page on navbar, ex. from page **works** or **about** to **home**, it change top position of the page or slightly scrolls.

So what's I'm trying to achieve is that, if the user click to every page it get to the top of the page position not slightly change position or scrolls.

**My current result:**

[image: My current navbar navigation issue]

**My `global.css` file.**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  background-color: #181a1b;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**My `navbar.js` file:**

```
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='flex flex-row justify-between mb-20 mt-16 sticky'>
        <Link to="/" className='a-title'>home</Link>
        <header className="flex flex-row">
            <Link to="/works" className='mr-6' activeClassName='text-green-400'>works</Link>
            <Link to="/about" activeClassName='text-green-400'>about</Link>
        </header>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

**The `layout.js` of every page:**

```
export default function Layout( { children } ) {
  return (
    <article className='max-w-2xl mx-auto'>
        <Navbar />
        { children }
        <Footer />
    </article>
  )
}
```

**The `homepage.js` sorry if this is a repetitive code down below:**

```
export default function index() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <main className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
        <article className="grid row-span-1 col-span-4 md:m-2 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-105 hover:animate-none cursor-pointer">
          <a href="/" className="a-footer">
            <StaticImage
              src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x250"
              alt="placeholder"
              placeholder="blurred"
              className="rounded-2xl object-cover"
            />
          </a>
        </article>
        <article className="grid row-span-1 col-span-4 md:m-2 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-105 hover:animate-none cursor-pointer">
          <a href="/" className="a-footer">
            <StaticImage
              src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x250"
              alt="placeholder"
              placeholder="blurred"
              className="rounded-2xl object-cover"
            />
          </a>
        </article>
        <article className="grid row-span-1 col-span-4 md:m-2 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-105 hover:animate-none cursor-pointer">
          <a href="/" className="a-footer">
            <StaticImage
              src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x250"
              alt="placeholder"
              placeholder="blurred"
              className="rounded-2xl object-cover"
            />
          </a>
        </article>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I am trying to achieve if the user click to every pages of navigation bar it should get to the top of the page position, not slightly change position after click every navigation bar menu.